# how can i remove owned tag without id or somthings ...via jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

how can remove selected input??

i created input tag with jquery

```
 $('#con').append('<input type="text">'+ '<span class="del">delete</span>');
```

i have button to create this.

and when i click button 3 times. the input will created 3 times too .
as you can see ;i set span tag with del class ; after input tag . i want when i click span tag. the tag (input) has clicked be remove . 
how can i do that?
 note : i have not any id's for inputs .

Comment: If `$('#icon')` is empty use `html()` instead of `append()` to solve first issue

Comment: tnx for reply friend

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it like this: As the delete button is added dynamically, you have to delegate the `click()` event from a static parent element like `document` to the span using `on()`. Use `prev()` to target the `<input>` that is before the `<span>` and `$(this).remove()` if you also want to remove the `<span>` tag.

```js
 $('#con').append('<input type="text">' + '<span class="del">delete</span>');
 $(document).on("click", ".del", function() {
   $(this).prev("input").remove();
   $(this).remove();
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="con">

</div>
```

Comment: thanks its true . how can i remove delete button during removing input tag?

Comment: @Alex By adding $(this).remove(); to the function. I'll also update this in my answer, I didn't know it was required.

Answer (score 0):

You have the id selector `#con`:

```
$('#con').on('click', '.del', function() {
  console.log('delete click');
});
```

You know the deal what you need to do now.

Comment: tnx for your reply